# How do you use partial fraction decomposition to break up $1/(s+4)^2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

How do you use [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to break up $1/(s+4)^2$?

The usual method isn't giving me an answer.

Comment: The answer is... $1/(s+4)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You have a double root. The equation is

$$f(s)=\frac{1}{(s+4)^2}=\frac{A}{(s+4)}+\frac{B}{(s+4)^2}$$

Now it is easy to calculate A and B.

**Remark:**

If you want to integrate $f(s)$, you don't need to look for partial fractions.

$\int \frac{1}{(s+4)^2} \ dx=\int (s+4)^{-2} \ dx=-(s+4)^{-2+1}+C$

Comment: But the purpose of partial fractions is to break it into two right? So how do I get A/(s+4) + B/(s+4)

Comment: @Goldname If you have a double root, then the right side is like I have posted. There have to be one fraction with a square in the denominator. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration

Comment: Yes I know what the rules are, so is it impossible to get it in the form of what I want?

Comment: Yes. For what purpose you want to do it like that ?

Comment: I initially wanted to find the inverse laplace transform of it, though now I realize that you do not need to break it apart. Anyways, I'm just surprised that there's no way to break this fraction apart.

Answer (score 0):

You are already done. You would write $\frac 1{(s+4)^2}=\frac A{s+4}+\frac B{(s+4)^2}$.  Clearly $A=0, B=1$ is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The *unicity* of partial fraction decomposition gives the answer: it is $\;\dfrac1{(s+4)^2}$.